# How do I get a BCM4311 wireless card working without an Internet connection?

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, huawei

I'm a first time user of Linux, I got the blue screen of death one to many times on an old laptop, a Dell D620, so I went for 12.04 and removed Windows, but now I can't get online at all.

We all use a Huawei E5830 WI-Fi as our only Internet access, but my wireless card won't work now with Ubuntu, is there a way to install the Huawei W5830 and connect through USB as with Windows? How can I get my wireless card to work? I also have a HUAWEI E1550 dongle that I can't get to work, I am looking for the easiest way to get back online.

If anybody can help me it would be amazing.

The card is Broadcom Corporation BCM4311.

Comment: Could you post the model of wi-fi card?
if you have any way to do it - try connecting to internet via cable and search dash for Additional Drivers - you might be able to download them.

Comment: the card is Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 thanks for the fast response.. but i cannot connect vie cable, wi-fi is our only internet access, im willing to give anybody that can help me get this working 20euro paypal donation, for there trouble, thanks, Kerry

Answer (score 1):

On your Ubuntu live media, you have the firmware cutter package, which you can use on a Broadcom Windows driver (bcmwl5.sys) from the wireless card install CD-ROM.
The location of b43-fwcutter package is:

```
/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_012-1build1_i386.deb
```

copy it to your home directory off the distribution media.

Install the b43-fwcutter package, and you should have the b43-fwcutter program installed in `/usr/bin` for you to run.  (If you can manage to get a wired connection, you will be offered the option to just download the appropriate Broadcom driver to run through the fwcutter).

Run it on the Windows driver bcmwl5.sys file, probably in an empty directory to make copying the .fw files easier.  The b43-fwcutter will "cut" out all the firmware files needed from the Broadcom driver.  Copy all the .fw files into `/lib/firmware/b43`, and you should see network-manager pick up the card.  Use `sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43` and
`sudo cp *.fw /lib/firmware/b43` to move the files.

This firmware is all that the b43 driver needs to run on your 4311 chip.  Since you haven't been connected to the Internet, you probably didn't manage to install any Broadcom drivers which would blacklist the b43 driver, so it should run automatically as soon as the firmware is supplied.  Reboot if necessary to see the available wireless access points.